# Hiding Command Prompt Window after running a command

Tags: console-application

I have a console application built in python. I start the application by giving some input parameters to it. I want the application to run in background after taking input.

Answer (score 0):

Put arguments into a text file, change its extension to `.bat`, [run](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-and-run-batch-file-windows-10) it.